# How to load the same component again in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to reload my `main.js` component but it is loading only one time when it is loaded for the first time.

My text animation works fine when the component is loaded for the first time, but when I visit different routes and the again visit the component the text animation stops.

```
class Main extends Component {

    typeWriter() {
        var TxtRotate = function (el, toRotate, period) {
            this.toRotate = toRotate;
            this.el = el;
            this.loopNum = 0;
            this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
            this.txt = '';
            this.tick();
            this.isDeleting = false;
        };

        TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function () {
            var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
            var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

            if (this.isDeleting) {
                this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
            } else {
                this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
            }

            this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + '</span>';

            var that = this;
            var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

            if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

            if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
                delta = this.period;
                this.isDeleting = true;
            } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
                this.isDeleting = false;
                this.loopNum++;
                delta = 500;
            }

            setTimeout(function () {
                that.tick();
            }, delta);
        };

        window.onload = function () {
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
                var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
                if (toRotate) {
                    new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
                }
            }
            // INJECT CSS
            var css = document.createElement("style");
            css.type = "text/css";
            css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
            document.body.appendChild(css);
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.typeWriter();
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div id="main" >
                    <h2 id="typeWrite" className="mt-4 mb-5">I'm a
                     <span className="txt-rotate" data-period="2000" data-rotate='[ " Developer.", " Programmer."]'></span>
                    </h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

How do I make the component load again?

Comment: You're not actually using react to perform the type writing effect, you're using the `window.onload` event... that only gets called once, so the next time the component loads, that callback won't be invoked again.

Comment: I'm new to React, so I don't have much knowledge about it. How should I fix this issue?

Comment: Take the stuff out of the window.onload and leave it in the parent function.  It's called when the document completes mounting anyway.  Additionally, why are you trying to inject css?  Why not have a separate stylesheet or do it inline inside your Component.render()?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a React stateful component to render the type writer effect, don't try to "break out" of React like you have with your `typeWriter()` method. I've written a fully-functioning demo using function components and React hooks below:

```js
const { useRef, useState, useReducer, useMemo, useEffect } = React;

const typeWriterInitialState = {
  index: 0,
  deleting: false,
  length: 0
};

const typeWriterReducer = (state, action) => {
  const { index, deleting, length } = state;
  const { text, fullText } = action;

  if (deleting && text === '') return {
    index: index + 1,
    deleting: false,
    length: length + 1
  };

  if (!deleting && text === fullText) return {
    index: index,
    deleting: true,
    length: length - 1
  };

  return {
    index,
    deleting,
    length: length + (deleting ? -1 : 1)
  };
};

function useTypeWriter (props) {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [period] = useState(props.period || 2000);
  const [rotate] = useState(props.rotate);
  const [state, update] = useReducer(
    typeWriterReducer,
    typeWriterInitialState
  );
  const { index, deleting, length } = state;
  const fullText = rotate[index % rotate.length];
  const text = fullText.substring(0, length);
  const delta = useMemo(() => {
    if (text === fullText && !deleting) return period;
    if (text === '' && deleting) return 500;
    return (200 * Math.random() + 100) * (deleting ? 0.5 : 1);
  }, [text, fullText, deleting, period]);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.textContent = text;

    const timeout = setTimeout(update, delta, { text, fullText });

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [ref, delta, text, fullText, update]);

  return ref;
}

const wrapStyle = { borderRight: '0.08em solid #666' };

function TypeWriter (props) {
  const { period, rotate } = props;
  const wrapEl = useTypeWriter({ period, rotate });

  return (
    <span ref={wrapEl} style={wrapStyle}/>
  );
}

const mainRotate = ['Developer.', 'Programmer.'];

function Main () {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>I'm a <TypeWriter period={2000} rotate={mainRotate}/></h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.body);
```

```css
h2 {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```